# How to concatenate two strings in different rows in SQL (Snowflake)?

Tags: sql, concatenation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have data as follows in Snowflake:

```
   Question       Answer    ID
First name?         John   001
 Last name?        Smith   001
First name?         Avon   002
 Last name?    Barksdale   002
First name?     Stringer   003
 Last name?         Bell   003
```

Is there anyway to `CONCATENATE` these to the following?

```
ID       Full_Name
001     John Smith
002 Avon Barksdale
003  Stringer Bell
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `listagg` for this:

```
SELECT listagg(answer,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY question)
FROM x
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Awesome answer :-) ... nice use of WITHIN GROUP

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       concat_ws(' ',
                 (case when question = 'First name?' then answer end),
                 (case when question = 'Last name?' then answer end)
                ) as fullname
from t
group by id
```